# Can't `mov` directly to registers - x86 Assembly on OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm a total beginner in x86 Assembly (although I have some basic experience with MIPS and I'm pretty familiar with MIPS assembly code), and I'm trying to understand how it works. For the moment being I'm just working on a simple hello world program that just prints a string to `stdout`.

If I'm not mistaken, in order to print something to `stdout` the following registers should contain the following values:

- `edx` should contain the length of the string
- `ecx` should contain the pointer to the string
- `ebx` should contain the file descriptor value (0x1 for `stdout`)
- `eax` should contain the syscall value (0x4 for `write`)

However, while I've made sure that all the registers have the correct values (by checking with `lldb`), I get nothing printed on `stdout`.

As I'm on an OSX machine, I'm assembling and linking with `nasm` and `ld` respectively, as follows:

```
$ nasm -f macho -O0 hello.asm
$ ld -e _start -lSystem -macosx_version_min 10.8 hello.o -o hello
```

Where `hello.asm` is the source code file. The `-O0` flag on the first command tells the assembler to not optimize the code, so that I can look at it later with `lldb`; also the `_start` label is the entry point to my program (see code below) and `-lSystem` is needed or else `ld` refuses to compile (the `-macosx_version_min` flag is there to silence `ld` warnings).

Here is the code that should work but doesn't:

```
section .data ; Beginning of our data section

msg db "Hello, World!", 0xa ; String with a carriage-return
len equ $ - msg ; String length in bytes


section .text ; Start of the code indicator
global _start ; Make the main function externally visible

_syscall: ; Declaring a kernel call function
    int 0x80 ; Make the system call
    ret ; Return to the caller

_start: ; Entry point for linker

; Write our string to standard output
mov edx, len
mov ecx, msg
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4 ; System call number (sys_write)
call _syscall ; Call the kernel

mov ebx, 0 ; Exit code
mov eax, 0x1 ; System call number (sys_exit)
call _syscall ; Make the system call
```

This code fails in two points: it prints nothing, and also its exit code is not 0 (on my machine it returns 0x51).

However, if I push the values onto the stack, it works perfectly:

```
section .data ; Beginning of our data section

msg db "Hello, World!", 0xa ; String with a carriage-return
len equ $ - msg ; String length in bytes


section .text ; Start of the code indicator
global _start ; Make the main function externally visible

_syscall: ; Declaring a kernel call function
    int 0x80 ; Make the system call
    ret ; Return to the caller

_start: ; Entry point for linker

; Write our string to standard output
push dword len ; Push message length onto stack (for EDX)
push dword msg ; Push message to write onto stack (for ECX)
push dword 1 ; Push file descriptor value (STDOUT) onto stack (for EBX)
mov eax, 4 ; System call number (sys_write)
call _syscall ; Call the kernel

push dword 0 ; Exit code 
mov eax, 0x1 ; System call number (sys_exit)
call _syscall ; Make the system call
```

What is causing this? Does it have something to do with register size? I want to work in 32-bit mode and I'm pretty sure I am, because I know that in order to assemble in 64-bit mode I need to call nasm with `-f macho64`.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: 32-bit MacOS system calls on BSD do not use registers (except for the system call number in EAX), they use the stack for parameters except for the system call number that is in EAX.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you. So every time I see x86 Assembly code that uses registers for system calls, I should use the stack instead?

Comment: SInce you are writing 32-bit code you have to make sure that the code you are finding online is for 32-bit MacOS. 32-bit Linux programs use registers, and the system call numbers are different than MacOS. System calls in 32-bit applications on MacOS uses the stack. Do not use system call code written for Linux or other OSes

Comment: @jimkokko5 System calls work differently on each operating system.  A Linux example will not work on macOS.

Comment: linked from [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](//stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) - 
 http://www.int80h.org/bsdasm/#default-calling-convention